# How to simplify the copy content code?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel, vba

I have a series of code to trace the file path and trace out the data from multiple excel file.

I was wondering is there any way I can modify the code so I do not need to keep copy and paste the same code by just changing the cell value?

**Here will be the code:**

```
Sub FetchData()

Dim shDestin As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set shDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
CopyFileContent Range("B11").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 11
CopyFileContent Range("B12").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 12
CopyFileContent Range("B13").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 13
CopyFileContent Range("B14").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 14
CopyFileContent Range("B15").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 15
CopyFileContent Range("B16").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 16
CopyFileContent Range("B17").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 17
CopyFileContent Range("B18").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 18
CopyFileContent Range("B19").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
shDestin, 19
```

Is there any way like it can set range like  `B11:B19` then `shDestin 11:19`?
It will be trouble because in future I might have 50+ file in a folder to trace the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try *For Each* which I think is more readable.

```
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Range("B11:B19") '~~> or any range you want
    CopyFileContent cel.Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value _
        , shDestin, cel.Row
Next
```

Comment: @Kimberly Actually VinhNT's answer will work as well provided you declare and initialize the variables separately as I've commented in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
For index As Integer = 11 To 19
    CopyFileContent Range("B" & cstr(index) ).Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, shDestin, index 
Next i
```

`"B" & cstr(index)` will be convert to "B11" to "B19" in the loop

Comment: hi, @VinhNT, it show syntax error For index As Integer = 11 To 19

Comment: This wouldn't work in VBA. VB.Net allows declaring and initializing variable in one line, not VBA. To fix, `Dim i As Interger` then on a separate line `For i = 11 To 19`.

Comment: Thank you~ I have fixed it~